# Is it possible to create a custom skill that blocks all skills on Echo dot and unlocks only with a secret code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, echodot

I would like to create a custom skill that will block all skills and unlock only if I say a secret code to it.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Your skill will not have any control over other skills.

However, for voice purchasing, you can turn ON a 4 digit pass code.